# Proof of Rudin's Theorem 7.29

Tags: analysis

In the baby rudin, I have some difficulties in understanding the concept of uniform closure of an algebra in Definition 7.28 and Theorem 7.29. The definition of the uniform closure is:

> Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of all functions which are limits of uniformly convergent sequences of members of an algebra $\mathscr{A}$. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is called the uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$.

If I understand it correctly, $\mathscr{B}$ is a set of all limit functions, so, even though $\mathscr{B}$ is called the CLOSURE of $\mathscr{A}$, $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{B}$ does not hold in general. On the other hand, if $E \subset X$ of a metric space X and $E'$ is a set of all limit points of $E$, then $\bar{E} = E' \cup E$ is the closure of $E$ and $E \subset \bar{E}$.

Now, in the proof of Theorem 7.29, the first part proves $\mathscr{B}$ is an algebra and the second part is:

> By Theorem 2.27, $\mathscr{B}$ is (uniformly) closed.

Here Theorem 2.27 (a) is:

> If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subset X$, then $\bar{E}$ is closed.

So, the logic I can find in the second part is that $\mathscr{B}$ is a closure of $\mathscr{A}$, so it is closed by Theorem 2.27. However, the definition of the closure of an algebra seems different to the definition of the closure of a generic set and $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{B}$ seems necessary to follow that logic. What am I missing here?

By the way, I can prove the second part in a different way, so Theorem itself does not make any trouble.

Comment: A must be fully contained in B. You should note the difference between a *limit* and a *limit point*. In your case, if $f\in A$, take $f_n=f$ for all $n$, then $f$ is the uniform limit of $f_n$, a sequence in $A$, and hence belongs to B.

Comment: @Vim Thanks. The problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, Rudin introduces $\mathcal{B}$ as a set of limit points for sequences that may be constructed based on points of $\mathcal{A}$. Then he immediately **defines** $\mathcal{B}$ as a closure of $\mathcal{A}$.

This is wrong.

Basically he mixes the notion of a closure (see **definition 2.26**) and the notion of a collection of limit points for sequences in $\mathcal{A}$. In other words, closure defined as

$$ \overline{E} = E \cup E' \qquad \text{Def 2.26}$$

implies

$$ \mathcal{B} = \overline{\mathcal{A}} = \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{A}'  \qquad (*) $$

whereas the introductory phrase that really confuses it all means

$$ \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}' \qquad (**) $$

In both cases $ \mathcal{B} $ will contain its limit points, whether they belong to $\mathcal{A}'$ or to $\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{A}'$.

Suppose we took the wrong path(**). That is, if we take the limit points of $\mathcal{A}$, (namely $\mathcal{A}'$), construct a sequence out of them, the limit [function] of this sequence will be the limit for the original $\mathcal{A}$.

This is because every neighborbood of such limit point (=function) will contain a point of $\mathcal{B}$, and each neighborbood of $\mathcal{B}$ in its turn, being a limit point for $\mathcal{A}$, will contain a point of $\mathcal{A}$.

Whatever the limit function for $\mathcal{B}$, all its neighborhoods "capture" points of $\mathcal{A}$, so it belongs to $\mathcal{B}$. We thus proved for (**).

Proof for (*) is use **Theorem 2.27a** as a template.

Therefore $\mathcal{B}$ is closed in both cases, (*) and (**).

Answer (score 0):

Please point out if there are any errors in the below reasoning regarding uniform closure from Definition 7.28 in Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Below, we will try to show that closure (Definition 2.26) and uniform closure (Definition 7.28) are identical.

Definition 2.26: If $E\subset X$ of a metric space $X$ and if $E'$ denotes the set of all limit points of $E$ in $X$, then $\bar{E}=E'\cup E$ is the closure of $E$.

Relevant part of Definition 7.28: $\mathscr{B}$ is the set of all functions which are limits of uniformly convergent sequences of members of an algebra $\mathscr{A}$. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is called the uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$.

First we will show that $\mathscr{A}$ is a subset of $\mathscr{B}$. For any element, $f\in\mathscr{A}$, then we can form a sequence $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$  taking all $f_{n}$ to be $f$, and this sequence will approach $f$ uniformly, so it will belong to the uniform closure, $\mathscr{B}$. Hence, $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$.

Second, we will show that $\mathscr{A}'\subseteq\mathscr{B}$. Any limit point $f$ of $\mathscr{A}$ will have a sequence $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$  in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $f=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f_{n}$. [Theorem 3.2 (d)]. Hence, $\mathscr{A}'\subseteq\mathscr{B}$.

The above imply that $\mathscr{A}\cup\mathscr{A}'\subseteq\mathscr{B}\Rightarrow\bar{\mathscr{A}}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$

Lastly, we will show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a subset of the closure of $\mathscr{A}$, that is $\mathscr{B}\subseteq\bar{\mathscr{A}}$. Suppose, $f\in\mathscr{B}$ and $f=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f_{n}$ where every $f_{n}\in\mathscr{A}$ then we need to show that $f\in\bar{\mathscr{A}}$. If $f\in\mathscr{A}$ then $f\in\bar{\mathscr{A}}$. If $f\notin\mathscr{A}$ then since $f=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f_{n}$ we have $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N\;s.t.\quad n\geq N\Longrightarrow d\left(f_{n},f\right)<\varepsilon$. Here, $d\left(\right)$ is the distance corresponding to the the metric space, which could be the uniform norm or supremum norm (Definition 7.14) but could be some other metric as well. Choose $N$ such that $\quad\varepsilon N>1\Rightarrow1/N<\varepsilon\Rightarrow1/n<\varepsilon$ because $1/n\leq1/N$. Also since, $1/n>1/\left(n+1\right)>1/\left(n+2\right)\ldots$ there are an infinite number of points (functions, $f_{n}$, here) within the neighborhood of radius $\varepsilon$ around $f$. Since this was an arbitrary neighborhood (since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary), $f$ is a limit point of $\mathscr{A}$ [Theorem 2.20]. Hence, $f\in\mathscr{A}'\subseteq\bar{\mathscr{A}}\Rightarrow\mathscr{B}\subseteq\bar{\mathscr{A}}$.

Hence, we have shown that the closure and uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$ are the same, that is $\bar{\mathscr{A}}=\mathscr{B}$.

An example where $\mathscr{A}$ is not necessarily closed is the set of polynomials. Consider the algebra of all polynomial functions on an interval $\left[a,b\right]$. Theorem 7.26 (Weierstrass theorem) shows that its uniform closure (or closure) is the algebra of all continuous functions on $\left[a,b\right]$, but the algebra of all polynimials itself does not contain all continuous functions, so it is not closed.

Hence, I am unsure about whether Definition 7.28 requires set $\mathscr{A}$ to be closed or whether $\mathscr{A}$ has to be a subset of a compact metric space (in which case it is closed and bounded). Above, we have tried to show this without explicitly assuming that we are working in a compact metric space or that set $\mathscr{A}$ is closed. Assuming that $\mathscr{A}$ is compact (or closed) might (will?) make it easier, but it does not seem to be necessary.

Regarding the second part of Theorem 7.29, since $\mathscr{B}=\bar{\mathscr{A}}$ it is (uniformly) closed due to [Theorem 2.27]